# Best way to analyze similarity of two datasets

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, data-analysis

So I'm looking for the best way to analyze 2 datasets and compare how similar they are. Each dataset consists of data from each point in a swipe gesture and I need to analyze how similar they are based on this data. I would prefer to do this in objective c but c++ and swift work as well.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is there anything you tried so far?

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions for algorithmic strategy, suggestions for the best programming language for the purpose, something else?

Comment: @r-sahu I'm looking for algorithmic strategy or library suggestions. Sorry it wasn't clear

Comment: What do you mean by 'similar'? There are tons of metrics ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics) )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach for solving this problem is to use "Artificial neural networks". They are really good at comparing two sets of data and return the amount of similarity.
Check out the link below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network

I hope this will help you.